# KQL return size of tables in a LAW with size in GB, MB, KB

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I want to calculate the size of each table in a given Log Analytics workspace and have the sizes returned in GB, MB etc. The following code works partially , but since I'm not using the `units` arg the `format_bytes` func is not returning expected results for large values.

```
union withsource= table *
| where TimeGenerated between(datetime(2022-05-02) ..datetime(2022-05-03))
| summerize Size = sum(_BilledSize) by table, _IsBillable | sort by Size desc | extend Size2 = format_bytes(toint(Size), 2)
```

How could I overcome it, or perhaps solve my problem in a different way?
[image: KQL results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're casting a `double` value (`Size`) to an `int` before invoking `format_bytes()`.

instead of this:

`extend Size2 = format_bytes(toint(Size), 2)`

try this:

`| extend Size2 = format_bytes(Size, 2)`

```
datatable(Size:double)
[
    17404157113,
]
| extend Your_Size2 = format_bytes(toint(Size), 2),
         Better_Size2 = format_bytes(Size, 2)
```

| Size | Your_Size2 | Better_Size2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17404157113 | -2147483648 Bytes | 16.21 GB |

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm casting it becuase per the docs "The _BilledSize column specifies the **size in bytes** of data that will be billed to your Azure account if _IsBillable is true." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-standard-columns#_billedsize Since the `format_bytes()` arg `value` - `a number to be formatted as data size in bytes.` will this not break stuff?

Comment: i don't understand the conflict. could you clarify why casting to a 32-bit wide integer is required?

Comment: Hi, tbh if I think about it now, I don't see reason for casting it. Thank you! Could you please tell me if I could run this query across multiple Log Analytics workspaces at once? But in such a way that it would return results per LAW instead of combining it in one table ?

Comment: Consider opening another question for that. I'm not personally familiar with log analytics workspaces

Comment: Sure, Yoni - thank you for your help :)!